# How to increase the sensitivity range of MQ3 Alcohol sensor?

Tags: electrical-engineering, sensors

I am using an MQ3 sensor for alcohol detection but the sensing distance is short. Is there any alternative approach or solution to detect alcohol present in air from a longer distance?

For example, the drunken driver exhales ethanol vapours, the sensor placed at steering should detect the alcohol content. 
But MQ3 sensors cannot detect the ethanol vapours at that distance. Is there any solution to this?

Comment: How do you control the air currents? wind ? Door opens etc?

Comment: currently I am using only the sensor , I  need solution to pull the air currents or person's exhaled air .

Comment: So, if the person is standing in a windy street how are you going to get the sample? Why do you think the testers the police use have people blow directly into the device?

Comment: I dont want to detect it in open space , detection should happen in small closed space like car driver's compartment , at 2 feet range .

Comment: Then you should improve your question as, at the moment, it is not clear.

Comment: cops use the tube to avoid ethanol vapours getting dispersed .

Comment: my sincere apologies about the question .

Comment: The trouble with what you want to do is the sensor is designed to receive air by the shortest route possible from the person being tested. By trying to test a person at a distance, the reading will be lower than that taken directly from a person's mouth because the sample will be diluted by air from the atmosphere (from the car or room). To avoid diluting the sample a long tube would be needed & the person being tested would need to blow harder. I assume you may want to test someone without the person knowing. In which case you will need to get a sensor calibrated for test at such distances.

Comment: Can connecting sensors in series will work ?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish exactly? It sounds like you want to have a device in a car that detects the driver's level of inebriation, why not just have them blow into a tube before the car starts? Why do you have to detect their breath at range?

Comment: The driver shouldn't be aware of the alcohol detection system . That's how I should design the working model.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that following [MQ3 Alcohol Gas Sensor](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/Biometric/MQ-3%20ver1.3%20-%20Manual.pdf) is the sensor referenced in this question. Per the specification the ***detection range*** is ***25-500 ppm*** of Alcohol. The sensitivity is

$$\frac{R_{o(in \ air)}}{R_{s(125ppm\ C_{2}H_{5}OH)}} \ \leq \ 5$$

Alternatively take a look at [MEMS Alcohol Gas Sensor GM-302B](http://www.winsensor.com/products/MEMS/MEMSjjqtcgqGM_302B_661.html) (note the link is in Chinese, so please use translate) which has a **detection range** of **1-500 ppm** of alcohol. Also the sensitivity is 1.2 to 50,

[image]

References:

- [MQ3 Alcohol sensor](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/a/22428/110)
- [Ultra-Low Power Gas Sensor for Ethanol Detection](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Austriamicrosystems%20PDFs/CCS803.pdf)