# MQ3 Alcohol sensor

Tags: electrical-engineering, sensors

I have done my project on alcohol detection for drivers, but I don't know the minimum and maximum distances between the alcohol sensor and the driver.
What are the maximum and minimum distances?

Answer (score 1):

MQ-3 Alcohol Sensor is base the amount ethanol molecules that is present near the electrodes. Therefore minimum and maximum distance had no or little bearing.

To give a little insight in to how the MQ3 sensor works.

The sensing element as shown in the picture below is a cuboid structure made out of an Alumina (Yellow) tube covered with Tin Dioxide (Light Brown). The electrode which is made out of Aurum is shown in Black.

[image]

The pin out and a drive circuit for the sensor are shown below.

[image: MQ3 Sensor pin out]

[image: MQ3 Circuit]

The above circuit activate the heating element.

[image]

As a result electrons begin to move because Tin Oxide ceramics has become a semi-conductor.

[image]

Now when air with alcohol elements enter the cuboid structure the circuit generate additional current because the ethanol burns into Acetic acid.

[image]

Therefore the minimum or maximum distance has no bearing, but the presence of alcohol will have significant effect on the sensor. For more detail information review the references.

References:

- [Sensor Report - MQ3 Gas sensor](http://sensorworkshop.blogspot.com/2008/04/sensor-report-mq3-gas-sensor.html)
- [MQ135 Alcohol Sensor Circuit And Working](https://www.elprocus.com/mq-135-alcohol-sensor-circuit-and-working/)
- [Alcohol Gas Sensor](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/Biometric/MQ-3%20ver1.3%20-%20Manual.pdf)